# url with % doesn't get to api

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Hi trying to get a signUrl from S3, for some reason making the call with % isn't parse correctly by my code. I get a 404 not found.

This is the ajax request:

https://stage.musicmarkers.com/website/api/admin/get-signed-url/thumbnail/magazine%2F2BE.gif/image%2Fgif

My API:

```
app.get('/website/api/admin/get-signed-url/thumbnail/:key/:type', auth.getMember, directives.noCache, getThumbnailSingedUrl);
```

My function:

```
function getThumbnailSingedUrl(req, res) {

    if (!isAdmin(req, res)) {
        return;
    }

    var key = req.params.key || '';
    var type = req.params.type || '';

    ThumbnailBucketFacade.getSignedUrl(
        'putObject',
        key,
        type,
        function onGotSignedUrl(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                RestResponse.serverError(res, error);
            } else {
                RestResponse.ok(res, result);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Making the call in a dev environment works.

Making the call without % environment works.

Same code exactly in a different project works.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's a lot odd with this question, it would probably help if you show us what you show us a working URL, you're describing this as if you don't know what the % in a URL means

Comment: Hi Nick, it is something to do with the environment no idea what. This exact call is working in a different environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually it was a configuration issue at 'nginx', the 'nginx' router

was configured to add '/' at the end of the site name. That made all the

other slashes scrambled and ultimately to the call not to be recognise.

Thank's for those helping.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have is encoded URI. So you need to decode it before using it:

```
const key = req.params.key && decodeURIComponent(req.params.key) || '';
const type = req.params.type && decodeURIComponent(req.params.type) || '';
```

More on decoreURIComponent [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

This is also backward compatible, so you don't have to worry that a plain string will get mangled.

Comment: Hi, Gopikrishna S, unfortunately this is not the issue, I do not get to the function... we get 404 to the api not to S3

Comment: @utabmedia that probably means one of these two are throwing `auth.getMember`, `directives.noCache`. You should try adding a plain callback before everything else and try to debug it using a rest client like postman. Make sure its not url, then it will be clear where it is failing. Or try narrowing it down by removing said handlers one by one.

Comment: we do use 'auth.getMember, directives.noCache'. I tried postman still 404. I cant find a previous step to my api .. It is super narrowed down the call doesn't work with % but do without.. it also works in different environment but thats a bit hard to convey here.. thank's for your efforts

Comment: I repeat: check the implmentations of `auth.getMember` and `directives.noCache`. Its where its failing, assuming your statement 'unfortunately this is not the issue, I do not get to the function... we get 404 to the api not to S3' still stands true. Try taking those out one by one .. i.e try `app.get('...', getThumbnailSingedUrl);`,`app.get('...', directives.noCache, getThumbnailSingedUrl);`, and `app.get('...', auth.getMember, getThumbnailSingedUrl);` to narrow down your problem